# What does "credits being minor" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Up to now, her Hollywood movie credits have been minor.

(LA Times: [In China's 'money worshiping' movie industry, stars' high pay becomes a target of the central government](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fg-china-actors-pay-20180705-story.html#))

I think credits here means this kind of thing,
[image]

I know minor means small, child. It doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Yes, I know credits, but what is "credits have been minor"?

Comment: I know minor means small, child. It doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Dictionary.com

> - [credit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/credit)
>
>   3. the ascription or acknowledgment of something as due or properly attributable to a person, institution, etc.: *She got a screen credit for photography*.
> - [minor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/minor)
>
>   1. lesser, as in size, extent, or importance, or being or noting the lesser of two: *a minor share*.

When an actor receives *credit* on a show or movie, it means they played a role and their name was acknowledged in a list at the end of the film for that role. The list at the end is called the [closing credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits), often *the credits*. What the article is trying to say is that she has been credited with minor roles, or that her roles were minor.

The article immediately goes on to say

> She appeared in “X men: Days of Future Past” as a mutant called Blink, a name befitting her brief talking scene, and she was cast as an unnamed nurse in “Iron Man 3,” a U.S.-China co-production that added scenes of Fan for the Chinese market.

[In that X-Men movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past), she played a minor role in a brief talking scene, as opposed to [Hugh Jackman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Jackman), who had a major role playing the iconic [Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)).

Answer (score -2):

Credits here doesn't mean "The list of people who helped to make a film, a CD, or a television programme".

It means reputation here.

So, the sentence here means her reputation is small in Hollywood.